# Import excel files using Paperclip, S3 and Roo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to import an excel file using Paperclip and save it to S3 then extract and parse using the Roo gem.

When I attempt something like this:

```
  @excel = Excel.new(@manifest.attachment.url)
```

I get the following error:

```
 http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/attachments/22/manifest.xls?1343835058 is not an Excel file
```

I'm guessing the appended timestamp on the end of the filename is causing Roo to not think this is an Excel file.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the timestamp you need to pass the 'false' argument in the url method.

For you : @excel = Excel.new(@manifest.attachment.url)

you should try with  @excel = Excel.new(@manifest.attachment.url(:original, false)) then you will be getting the following url:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/attachments/22/original/manifest.xls

But if you are trying to retrieve the image url then you should have @manifest.attachment.url(:large, false). Note: it can be :large, :medium or your customized styles in the model.

I hope that this might help you to solve your issues.

thanks